# GDAL - Convert QGIS raster calc expression to valid syntax for gdal_calc

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I have been using QGIS `Raster Calculator` to patch Raster Bs values in where Raster As are 0 using the below expression

```
("A@1" = 0) * "B@1" + ("A@1" != 0) * "A@1"
```

I now want to do this using `gdal_calc` within a python script, but it keeps throwing up the error that my formula is an invalid syntax. How can I achieve the same results?

```
gdal_calc --calc "(A = 0) * B + (A != 0) * A" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\Users\Public\try\A.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\Users\Public\try\B.tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/public/OUTPUT.tif
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue! thanks. Can you put this as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdal_calc` uses python syntax. In python `=` is used for variable assignment and `==` is for equality checking.

E.g.

```
>>> a = 123   
>>> print(a)
123 
>>> a == 123
True
>>> a == 1234
False
```

So the following should work:

```
gdal_calc --calc "(A == 0) * B + (A != 0) * A" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\Users\Public\try\A.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\Users\Public\try\B.tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/public/OUTPUT.tif
```